# Searching availability with Dates in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I'm trying find the right SQL query for my PHP project, so here is three tables :

- person :

| p_id | p_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Lance Hope |
| 2 | Karen Hume |
| 3 | Brenden Bowden |
| 4 | Danyal Lowry |
| 5 | Samiya Dalby |

- field :

| f_id | f_from | f_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-04 | 2022-06-30 |
| 2 | 2022-07-05 | 2022-08-20 |
| 3 | 2022-03-15 | 2022-04-17 |
| 4 | 2022-10-20 | 2022-11-13 |
| 5 | 2022-06-30 | 2022-05-20 |

- affect :

| a_id | fk_f_id | fk_p_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 3 | 5 |
| 7 | 4 | 5 |
| 8 | 5 | 2 |

And I have a reference Date that sets an interval, for exemple lets take the following case :
$from = 2022-04-25 , $to = 2022-07-08

So we are with this:
[image]

Now I would like to have the right SQL query to show this result table of avaibilities for the interval :

| p_id | available_from | available_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-30 | 2022-07-05 |
| 3 | - | 2022-10-20 |
| 4 | 2022-04-17 | - |
| 5 | 2022-04-17 | 2022-10-20 |

By the way, the person with id = 2 isn't in this table because he is not available for the interval.
I already tried with a big SQL query with plent of "OR" and "AND" and sort after in PHP to not have a person several times in table, something like this :

```
SELECT a.*, p.*
    FROM person p
    inner join affect a on a.fk_p_id = p.p_id    
    where ((a.a_from <= $from AND (a.a_to >= $from and a.a_to <= $to)) 
    OR (a.a_from >= $to AND a.a_to >= $to) 
    OR (a.a_from <= $from AND a.a_to <= $from) 
    OR (a.a_to >= $from and (a.a_to <= $to AND a.a_to >= $to)) )
```

And I would like my result to be merged like the table above. I have bases but I can't build it properly. Thanks if you try to help me and if you have a question I will answer as fast as possible.

Comment: Do you search for records which fall completely into your search interval, or also partly?

Comment: I don't know if you saw but I made te result table that I would like to have. I need persons that are availables for that interval (wich is a "field" himself), to affect person into it

Comment: Please see my answer, it should resolve all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you're searching for records which fall completely into your search range, this should do:

```
WHERE a.a_from >= 'from_date' AND a.a_to <= 'to_date'
```

The counterpart (find the records which are completely outside the range) would be this:

```
WHERE a.a_to < 'from_date' OR a.a_from > 'to_date'
```

To find the overlapping records, try this:

```
WHERE ('from_date' BETWEEN a.a_from AND a.a_to) OR ('to_date' BETWEEN a.a_from AND a.a_to)
```

Comment: Okay thanks, and in php if I want to return a table like the result one I made in my question (replacing ids by names), I just have to use if statement ? To show from and to availability Dates, or hide if there is not a Date

Comment: You can use case C to find all those records which overlap with your search range (it will include case A), but you'd then have to repeat the checks in PHP to sort out, when to show what.

Comment: The overlap test can be done more simply with 2 inequalities and no Betweens.  I challenge you to discover it.