# Sort avaibility table with Date interval in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, web, intervals

I have a 3 columns table with : Name of workers, and avaibility dates (from and to) :

| workers | available from | available to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aiden | 2022-05-13 | / |
| Iona | 2022-05-13 | / |
| Connie | / | 2022-05-16 |
| Connie | 2022-05-13 | / |
| Connie | / | 2022-05-23 |
| Karen | 2022-05-13 | / |
| Karen | / | 2022-05-16 |

I also have an interval, let's say : from **2022-05-15**, to **2022-06-03**

And from there i would like to sort my table and merge all results with best Dates for the interval like this :

| workers | available from | available to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aiden | 2022-05-13 | / |
| Iona | 2022-05-13 | / |
| Connie | 2022-05-13 | 2022-05-16 |
| Karen | 2022-05-13 | 2022-05-16 |

Connie here is available to 2022-05-16 because we see an availability to the 23rd so we know that he works between the 16th and the 23rd.

I already did something with array comparison of values into it, in "for" loops, but i think i'm looking a little too far, because the code is very long and slow + doesn't works as I wish. Thanks for future help !

Comment: What is your data structure for that input?

Comment: *"Connie here is available to 2022-05-16 because we see an availability to the 23rd so we know that he works between the 16th and the 23rd."*: How do you know they work between 16th and 23rd? That would be in contradiction with "available to = 2022-05-23".

Comment: I had this problem too but if it can be fixed just by better sql query i'm glad to hear that, could you answer there pls ? [stackoverflow.com/questions/73400781](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73400781/searching-availability-with-dates-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

By observing the db values I think , if "available from" date is there then "available to" field value cannot be blank. I that case Connie "available from" 2022-05-13 and availabe to date will be 2022-05-23 by updating the "available to " field value. After that with the help of mysql query you can easly find the desired results.

Comment: sorry if this wasn't clear, please see my comment above to answer another post if you know sql well

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).